# Cisco ASA separating networks

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

We are using a Cisco ASA 5505 running ver 9.0 to separate our corporate (inside) network from a dev lab (outside) network. We would like to use NAT or PAT to forward the inside interface IP to a set host in the dev lab based on URL\Port used. Is this possible?

Exp. insideIP\jira would map to the jira server on port 80
     insideIP\console would map SSH to another lab host on port 22

The first step is the port 80 as that would go to a proxy server that would do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot NAT a URL. URLs work in the application layer and NAT in the IP layer, so your router's IP stack knows nothing about URLs.

Additionally, think this through: how would you instruct your SSH client to connect to a URL? You can't. You can tell your ssh client to connect to an IP:Port pair and that's all the info it can understand as far as where it's connecting to.

What you *can* do is port-forward port 80 through to an internal webserver. That's a fairly standard practice. You can also port-forward port 22 to an internal SSH host.

Comment: I should have known that, thanks. We are going to use either the workstation host file or DNS for the URL to IP translation. The other point on the port forwarding is can it be done forwarding inside to outside?

Comment: Example would be insideinterfaceIP:22 to outsideNet:22. They want to use the inside interface IP for all the forwarding since they have to point at that IP to get to the ASA anyway.